How do I handle a Git error in Powershell (Preferably V5 compatable)
I've never programed in PowerShell before, but I have coded in JS quite a bit so I'm not new to programming. I'm floundering around attempting to re-create my Bash script to automatically download BitBurner (An open source game on GitHub) and build it (Assuming there has been a new commit since the last time the script was run).
I'm mostly testing around right now to find out roughly what I'll need for the final script and I'm stuck on handling Git errors, the main one I'm focused on right now is fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git. Currently I can check for Git not being installed as well as the folder not existing, but but I want one more check to see if the folder is a valid Git repository in case the folder is empty or the .git folder is deleted for whatever reason.
My current code is this:
$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop';

$bbGamePath = 'G:/BitBurnerGame';

try {
    git --version; # Do nothing with this. This is a quick check to see if Git is installed or not
    Set-Location $bbGamePath;
    if (!(git fetch --dry-run -eq '')) {
         if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 128) { 
            Write-Error -Message 'Not a valid git repository.'
        };
    }
} catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Git is not installed!';
    # Should catch the Git Not Installed error, I can probably find this one.
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'Folder not found!';
    # Should catch the error of the folder not existing, Clone from the repo and continue from here.
} catch {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'Error 128';
    # Secondary to the above error, should throw if the folder exists but is not a valid git repository folder (AKA the .git folder does NOT exist)
}
Set-Location D:/;

I'm stuck trying to find some sort of solution similar to catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] but because git is an external cmdlet it seems there's no way of doing this in particular? Obviously I could just leave it as is but I would like a solution like the first two catches.
The ultimate plan btw is to release this script to the public, which is why I'm handling all of these cases.


I'm not sure if it is worth the effort, but you can define a custom exception class to represent the not-a-repo error condition and throw an instance of it, which you can then catch:
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$bbGamePath = 'G:/BitBurnerGame'

# Custom exception class.
class NotaGitRepoException: Exception {
  NotaGitRepoException([string] $Path) : base("Not a git repository: $Path") {}
}

try {
  # Create a temporary file to capture stderr output in.
  $stderrTempFile = New-TemporaryFile 
  $null = git --version
  Set-Location $bbGamePath
  git fetch --dry-run 2>$stderrTempFile
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 128) { throw ([NotaGitRepoException]::new($PWD)) }
  elseif ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw } # any other error reported by git
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Git is not installed!'
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'Folder not found!'
}
catch [NotaGitRepoException] {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $_
}
catch {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Unexpected git error ${LASTEXITCODE}: $((Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $stderrTempFile).Trim()))"
}
finally {
  # Clean up.
  Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $stderrTempFile
}

